# Add inline script for a dynamic created input button to download html table as excel format

Tags: javascript, html, excel, inline

https://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/

This is the original JSfiddle

The original JSfiddle allows me to dynamically create a download button for the HTML table as excel format;
however it calls from a function.

I'd like to change this in an inline method so it doesn't need to call the function
like so

https://jsfiddle.net/ekj40bLu/

Thank you for all the help in advance.

Somehow I can't get the idea how to change URI as inline way, any help would be much appreciated

```
 <input type="button" onclick="(function(){

    content of javascript from the function
            
            return false;
        })();return false;
        " value="Export to Excel">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE instead of linking to external sites.